# Cannot connect to LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, iis, localdb

I am trying to run an IIS-hosted app (in the form of a Movie Database) to teach myself how to design a 3-tier architecture program: MVC app, WCF Services, SQL Server DB. Since I don't have a license key to the full SQL Server I decided to go with LocalDB and have WCF services that wrap around my stored procedures. This is the first time I am using LocalDB and am running into issues connecting to my instance, v13.0.

**My Problem:**

I cannot, for the life of me, get my project in VS to connect to the LocalDB instance. I keep getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

My Connection String (from Web.config):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MovieDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v13.0;Initial Catalog=MovieDB;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MovieDB.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Using sqlcmd to connect to it and run queries runs fine:

[image: Connecting to LocalDB instance just fine from command line]

Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer can connect just fine:

[image: Visual SQL Server Object Explorer can connect just fine]

The connection string, as escaped by Visual Studio when it gets to the problematic line, so I know the connection string isn't escaped incorrectly:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\v13.0;Initial Catalog=MovieDB;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MovieDB.mdf"
```

I tried following this guide ([Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/) and [Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/)) and the images are broken as of at least 4/18/2016, so I wasn't able to fully understand what I'm supposed to do. I was only able to get the above error because I changed the app pool identity to LocalSystem:

[image: I was only able to get this error because I changed the app pool identity to LocalSystem]

When the app pool is running under the ApplicationPoolIdentity identity, I receive this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user.

I even went so far as to modify the C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config file to force profile loading. Still nothing.

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
    <add name="Classic .NET AppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
    <add name=".NET v2.0 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
    <add name=".NET v2.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" />
    <add name=".NET v4.5 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
    <add name=".NET v4.5" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <!-- I added this, before it was an empty node -->
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
    </add>
    <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <!-- This was already here -->
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
    </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>
```

My app is running under the ".NET 4.5" app pool

[image: My app is running under the ".NET 4.5" app pool]

**My Code:**

Page loads and calls this service to get the list of movies in the DB:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMovieDBService
{
    // ...

    [OperationContract]
    List<Movie> GetMovies(int actorID);

    // ...
}

public class MovieDBService : IMovieDBService
{
    // ...

    public List<Movie> GetMovies(int actorID = 0)
    {
        var output = new List<Movie>();
        using (var connection = DBTools.GetConnection(MovieDBConnectionName)) // Does not get past here; MovieDBConnection = "MovieDB"
        {
            var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
            {
                new SqlParameter("@actorID", actorID)
            };

            using (var reader = connection.ExecuteStoredProcedure("GetMovies", parameters))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    output.Add(new Movie
                    {
                        ID = reader.GetInt32("ID"),
                        Title = reader.GetString("Title"),
                        Year = reader.GetInt16("Year"),
                        Genre = GetGenre(reader.GetInt32("GenreID"))
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And the problematic method from my DBTools project:

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection(string connectionName)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection();
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName];
        if (connectionString != null)
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open(); // breaks here

            return connection;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I can only assume the problem has to do with authentication, or the fact that an IIS-hosted application is trying to connect to a LocalDB user process, but I've tried following instructions from other questions and have been unsuccessful (possibly because of failing to understand the real problem). I am at a loss...

Comment: LocalDB is for _development_, and is specific to the user that's trying to run it.  You may be better off switching the SQL Express in an ASP.NET environment.

Comment: @Chris Bowe Hey chris. I have got the same error. I was wondering how you solved it ?

Comment: I ultimately gave up trying to use LocalDB. I simply use SQL Server on my local with a newly-created DB and let EF crate the user tables on first registration in a new site.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: In your applicationhost file try to change processModel identityType to SpecificUser and also include username and password. OR change your app pool identity to the user that has permission to the database.  When you run as the application pool identity, based on your screenshots you are running as local system - which is a predefined local account whereas sqlcmd is running as the user you are logged in as.

Comment: I had to change mine to "LocalSystem".

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your IIS app pool account can't see the localdb instance because only the account that created the instance can access it, which is most likely your personal user account.  You can share it with other users on your machine (e.g. IIS app pool accounts) by running this command:

```
sqllocaldb share v13.0 v13.0_shared
```

We share the `v13.0` instance and name the shared instance `v13.0_shared`.  Then you would change the `Data Source` portion of your connection string to this:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\.\v13.0_shared
```

Notice the leading `.\` before the instance name.  This indicates that you are looking to connect to a shared instance.

Now all of your IIS app pools will be able to connect to the localdb instance without having to configure permissions for each one.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the entityFramework tag in your web.config ?
[image]

The parameter value should be your instance name.
Example for connection to that local db instance would be:

[image]